# Splash screen not appearing in iPhone only for iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, splash-screen

The app is build only for iPhone. It supports iOS6.0 and above.

All the splash screen images are added with proper resolutions and the corresponding options are selected in the attribute inspector.
[image]

But I do not see the splash screen only for iOS8!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splash screen rules changed from iOS 8. Probably you need to use a XIB or storyboard for landing screen. Please refer following :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Answer (score 11):

[image]

In XCode 6.1 For IOS 8...Use Launch Image Source as Launch Image...and Replace Launch Screen File from LaunchScreen.Xib to Blank..

Hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

I had a issue where an image placed on the LauchScreen.xib was not appearing even after a clean, clear derived data etc in **xcode 8**

My image was in the **Assets.xcassets** and somehow xcode got confused.  I removed the entry and re-added it and then it worked fine.

Just posting incase anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: Agreed however as like me who had LaunchScreen issues, this was the first question to appear and so it may help others out

Answer (score 0):

set the launch image to LaunchScreen.xib file, hope it will fix it up